# How do I start an invisible activity and then make it visible when ready?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to start activity `B` from `A`

But `B` takes quite some time to initialize

So I want to delay switching the view until `B` is ready.

Is there a way to start an invisible activity `B` and then make it visible when ready?

Comment: What makes B take so long to initialize? Can't you do that work from A or in a service or just an AsyncTask, which then starts B when the initializing work is done?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just try using AsyncTask. You can follow below steps !!

1) start Activity B ,  show a progressBar that can say "Screen is loading".

2) Load your screen into AsyncTask.

3) And when it is done remove the progress bar/dialog and show the screen,
 it is very Simple.

[AsyncTask Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: What merge ?? You need to start Activity A, then when u need to show, Start Activity B, and after that I already mentioned

Comment: it is not what you are thinking, this is recommended from documentation, AsyncTask is made for to load heavy operations, like screen loading if takes time, TO avoid ANR.

Comment: For some reason I have to do exactly as what I said above,do you mean it's impossible?

Comment: For what reason? Please either describe what needs to be initialized or post your code.

Comment: @new_perl i dint said it is possible or not, I mentioned what should be done and recommended. Please let us know what exactly u are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Start a background thread (AsyncTask for example) from activity A that it will do the initialization. When the AsyncTask finishes, start activity B.